# Find last group of numbers in regex

Tags: regex

I would like to identify year in sentence of last, how to find in Regex?

for ex:

string = some of texts 1999 some of texts 1986 some of text;

```
string = Regex.Replace(string, @"(\b(1[7-9]|2[0-9])\d{2}\b)", "<Year>$1</Year>");
```

my excepted output:

```
some of texts 1999 some of texts <year>1986</year>
```

Note: year will be more than one time
Thanks, Saran

Comment: `some of text` after year...will it be there or not?

Answer (score 2):

or use this pattern

```
(.*)(\b(?:1[7-9]|2[0-9])\d{2}\b)
```

and replace w/ `$1<Year>$2</Year>`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/131)

Comment: This would be the first thing I think about when I see "matching the last of `some pattern`"

Comment: @nhahtdh, exactly , hwnd and vks are over thinking it :-)

Comment: yeah overthought!!+1 ..sometimes great minds take diff. route :P

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(\d+)\b(?=[^\d]*$)
```

or

```
\b((?:1[7-9]|2[0-9])\d{2})\b(?=[^\d]*$)
```

Try this.Replace by `<year>$1</year>`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/20

Edit

```
\b((?:1[7-9]|2[0-9])\d{2})\b(?!.*\b((?:1[7-9]|2[0-9])\d{2})\b)
```

Use this if there are numbers ahead.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/21

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. if my string like: some of texts 1999 some of texts 1986 some 23 of text, its not working